# Dump docker-compose environment variables into file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Is there a way to dump the environment variables in the docker-compose.yml into a file on a given container?

Example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-api
    environment:
      - TOKEN=123
      - DB_NAME=db
```

I would like to create a .env file automatically inside the `api` container after the `docker-compose run -d` command.

Comment: Are you looking to get the complete environment the process starts with, or just the Compose-level overrides?  Does it need to take into account sources like `env_file:` and pass-throughs from the host environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze I need only the Compose-level overrides, like the 2 variables in the example. I don't need to take account of the `env_file` option, only the environment variables in the `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: I might try using a tool like `yq` to extract it from the YAML (though I don't have a recipe off hand), or a YAML-parsing library in your favorite language.

Comment: @DavidMaze And how do you write the extracted content into a file in the container?

Comment: What's your actual goal?  These values will be in the process environment; why do you need them in a file?  Can you bind-mount a config file instead of (or in addition to) setting the environment variables?  (I missed the "in the container" detail.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```yml
version: "3"

services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      API_URL: "test"
      TEST: "test"
    volumes:
      - envstorage:/env
    command: "cat /env/storeme"
    depends_on:
      - variable-storer
  variable-storer:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      TEST_1: "test"
      TEST_2: "test"
      TEST_3: "test"
      TEST_4: "test"
      TEST_5: "test"
      TEST_6: "test"
    volumes:
      - envstorage:/env
    command: "sh -c 'env > /env/storeme'"

volumes:
  envstorage:
    name: 'env-test'
```

NOTE: this is as hacky as it can be.